# @synchronized the writing queue makes thread safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

```
NSObject *token = [[NSObject alloc] init];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    while (1) {
        @synchronized (token) {
            array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1"];
        }
    }
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"%@",array);
    }
});
```

This code won't crash, even there is no `@synchronized` in the read queue.

As compared,

```
NSLock *lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    while (1) {
        [lock lock];
        array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1"];
        [lock unlock];
    }
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"%@",array);
    }
});
```

This code will crash as array is not thread safe. How does this one-side `@synchronized` keeps the thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

> How does this one-side `@synchronized` keeps the thread safe?

It doesn’t.

Using `@synchronized` (or any synchronization method) for writes, but not for reads, is not thread-safe. Just because your code does not readily crash does not mean it is thread-safe. Both reads and writes must be synchronized. Neither of these two examples, with unsynchronized reads, is thread-safe.

If you want to test for thread-safety, consider the [thread sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early) (TSAN). For example, when I ran the `@synchronized` example through TSAN, it reported:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=89608)
  Read of size 8 at 0x7b0c0007bce8 by thread T1:
    #0 __29-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke.14 <null> (MyApp12:x86_64+0x100002e3d)
    #1 __tsan::invoke_and_release_block(void*) <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x74d7b)
    #2 _dispatch_client_callout <null> (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x40af)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b0c0007bce8 by thread T3 (mutexes: write M1679):
    #0 __29-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke <null> (MyApp12:x86_64+0x100002c02)
    #1 __tsan::invoke_and_release_block(void*) <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x74d7b)
    #2 _dispatch_client_callout <null> (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x40af)

  Location is heap block of size 48 at 0x7b0c0007bcc0 allocated by main thread:
    #0 malloc <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x5239a)
    #1 _Block_object_assign <null> (libsystem_blocks.dylib:x86_64+0x14fc)
    #2 _Block_copy <null> (libsystem_blocks.dylib:x86_64+0x141c)
    #3 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] <null> (MyApp12:x86_64+0x100002878)
    #4 -[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad] <null> (AppKit:x86_64+0xb41ce)
    #5 start <null> (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

  Mutex M1679 (0x7b0400004020) created at:
    #0 objc_sync_enter <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x72a45)
    #1 __29-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke <null> (MyApp12:x86_64+0x100002b51)
    #2 __tsan::invoke_and_release_block(void*) <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x74d7b)
    #3 _dispatch_client_callout <null> (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x40af)

  Thread T1 (tid=3657833, running) is a GCD worker thread

  Thread T3 (tid=3657837, running) is a GCD worker thread

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race (/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ewpoprpgpjgbmrcrkyycvogiazhl/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp12.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp:x86_64+0x100002e3d) in __29-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke.14+0x6d
```

Whichever synchronization mechanism you use (whether `@synchronized`, locks, or GCD), both reads and writes must be synchronized. Data race problems are notoriously difficult to manifest, and, as such, one should hesitate to draw any conclusions from an absence of a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it work? Without going into technical details, and really just guessing, I *think* this has to do with the way in which the multithreading is implemented.

Reason is based on the following, which will also NOT crash

```
            NSLock * lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                int i = 0;

                while (1) {
                    lock.lock;

                    // Do some work
                    for ( int j = 0; j < 10000; j ++ )
                    {
                        double x = atan ( j );
                    }

                    array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@( i )];
                    lock.unlock;

                    i ++;
                }
            });
```

This is essentially the same as your code, but inside the lock I do some serious work. I think that work is 'hard' enough for the dispatcher to pause the other thread and I think once that work is done, the multithreading dispatcher says enough, time for some other threads, and then this one in turn is put on hold long enough for the other one to finish unmolested.

PS : That said, I think you will get different results as the load on the system changes and you need to properly sync access.